# How to use wp_footer() on a 404 page?

Tags: 404-error, footer

I am designing my 404 error page, for which I created a separate header and of course I need a separate footer. As for the latter, instead of creating a new one, would be enough for me to ensure the`wp_footer();` to be just before the closing body?

Or is there something in the `get_footer()` function that makes it necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_footer()` will bring footer.php, so including `wp_footer()` before the `</body>` will be more than enough in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create differents footers and headers files. For example, a default header.php and footer.php and specific templates like header-error.php and footer-error.php. In general, you will have this code to inclue header.php and footer.php:

```
get_header();
//Your page tempalte
get_footer();
```

In 404.php template file you can include header-error.php and footer-error.php as follow:

```
get_header('error');
//Your template
get_footer('error');
```

Or you can create a full 404.php template, including full header and full footer, without calling `get_header` and `get_footer` functions at all.

More info in [get_header()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) and [get_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was slightly different. I was after to understand whether the get_footer includes something that makes it necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to keep [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) in your footer.php. Although the codex says, and I quote

> Put this template tag immediately before  tag in a theme
>   template (ex. footer.php, index.php).

it is best keeping `wp_footer()` in the footer. From the PluginAPI for the [`wp_footer` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer)

> When included, the default output for this function is the admin panel
>   which will be shown in the top of the theme. It should be kept in the
>   footer for every theme because most of the plugin bind their script
>   files or functions to this hook.

To conclude, when creating a custom footer.php, include `wp_footer()` in this custom template as well.

**EDIT**

Just to elaborate more on your question. The closing `</body>` tag is the 2nd last tag called for a page, and is situated in the footer.php. Also, most importantly, the closing `</html>` tag is the last tag in the footer.php. This wraps up your site.

Have a look at the footer for the bundled theme, twentyfourteen

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains footer content and the closing of the #main and #page div elements.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
?>

        </div><!-- #main -->

        <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

            <?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>

            <div class="site-info">
                <?php do_action( 'twentyfourteen_credits' ); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
            </div><!-- .site-info -->
        </footer><!-- #colophon -->
    </div><!-- #page -->

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The last three lines of code is the most important.So it is very important to have a footer for these reasons as well, otherwise you will break the `<body>` and `<html>` tags. Don't leave out the footer, rather copy your footer.php, rename it, customize it, and call it where needed, and remember, don't move `wp_footer()` out of the footer

Comment: Added a link to the pluginAPI